# Need to get created data from multiple tables into 1 table

Tags: xml, split, insert, create-table, insert-update

I am relatively new to SQL and could use some help.  I have mashed together snippets of code that have helped me get close to my objective, but not achieve it.  The essentials of my original data looks like this:

- Product   - Qty_Shipping
- P65238 - - - - - 4
- P65236 - - - - - 2
- P65240 - - - - - 3

The essentials of what I want to end up with would look like this:

- Product - UCC Code
- P65238   - - 001475010
- P65238   - - 001475011
- P65238   - - 001475012
- P65238   - - 001475013
- P65236   - - 001475014
- P65236   - - 001475015
- P65240   - - 001475016
- P65240   - - 001475017
- P65240   - - 001475018

A unique UCC Code (beginning at:  001475010) must be assigned per quantity of product, to every shipment.  Below is the code that will create a number of unique UCCs base on the total quantity of products ordered.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(UCCs INT) 

DECLARE @UCC INT
    ,@textXML XML
    ,@data NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    ,@delimiter NVARCHAR(5)
    ,@ConCatString NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@LoopCounter INT
SET @ConCatString = ''
SET @UCC = 001475009 + 1
SET @LoopCounter = (
SELECT CAST(Q.DSPTOTQTY_0 AS INT)
FROM x3v6prem.PILOTNEW.SDELIVERY Q
WHERE Q.SOHNUM_0 = 'SO1300259')
IF @LoopCounter = 1 GOTO Skip_Loop
Continue_Loop:
SET @ConCatString = @ConCatString + CAST(@UCC AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ','
SET @UCC = @UCC + 1
SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter -1
IF @LoopCounter > 1 GOTO Continue_Loop
Skip_Loop:
SET @ConCatString = @ConCatString + CAST(@UCC AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 

SELECT @data = @ConCatString,
    @delimiter = ','
SELECT    @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)
INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Next is the code that will duplicate the product ID a number of times based on the quantity of the product being shipped.  In the end, the data will be used to create a shipping label that will placed on every box of product ordered and show a unique (barcode) number for each box.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP2(Products NVARCHAR(MAX)) 

DECLARE @Item2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@textXML2 XML
    ,@data2 NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    ,@delimiter2 NVARCHAR(5)
    ,@ConCatString2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@LoopCounter2 INT
    ,@LastLine2 INT
DECLARE CC CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT T.ITMREF_0
FROM x3v6prem.PILOTNEW.SDELIVERYD T
WHERE T.SOHNUM_0 = 'SO1300259'
ORDER BY T.SDDLIN_0
OPEN CC
SET @ConCatString2 = ''
SET @LastLine2 = (
SELECT CAST(L.DSPTOTQTY_0 AS INT)
FROM x3v6prem.PILOTNEW.SDELIVERY L
WHERE L.SOHNUM_0 = 'SO1300259')
GetNextItem2:
FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @Item2
IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 GOTO EndBothLoops2
SET @LoopCounter2 = (
SELECT CAST(Q.QTY_0 AS INT)
FROM x3v6prem.PILOTNEW.SDELIVERYD Q
WHERE Q.SOHNUM_0 = 'SO1300259' AND Q.ITMREF_0 = @Item2)
Continue_Loop2:
IF @LoopCounter2 = 0 AND @LastLine2 > 1 GOTO GetNextItem2
SET @ConCatString2 = @ConCatString2 + CAST(@Item2 AS  NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ','
SET @LoopCounter2 = @LoopCounter2 - 1
SET @LastLine2 = @LastLine2 - 1
IF @LoopCounter2 > 0 AND @LastLine2 > 1 GOTO Continue_Loop2
IF @LoopCounter2 = 0 AND @LastLine2 > 1 GOTO GetNextItem2
SET @ConCatString2 = @ConCatString2 + CAST(@Item2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
EndBothLoops2:
CLOSE CC
DEALLOCATE CC
SELECT @data2 = @ConCatString2
   ,@delimiter2 = ','
SELECT    @textXML2 = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data2, @delimiter2, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)

INSERT INTO #TEMP2
SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
FROM    @textXML2.nodes('/d') T(split)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP2
DROP TABLE #TEMP2
```

If I could simply figure out how to get the output that I have put into two separate tables into one table my problems would be solved and I could (I believe) manage the rest.  I have no real experience with the XML code that I am using so I cannot discern how to insert multiple columns into the table(s) being created.
Other smaller issues:  I cannot seem to format the UCC values in a way where they will keep their leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though I was able to solve my own problem.  I was finally able to add a second field to the tables I created by using the IDENTITY keyword.  At this point I am still uncertain as to why I was able to add this field and no other, but I'll take it!  The code I have written is still likely to be horribly ineffient, so if anyone wants to help me make the code run better, I would greatly appreciate it!  Thanks!!